# Error using Keras in R. "ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments."

Tags: r, keras, rstudio, recurrent-neural-network

So I'm trying to learn RNN in R using `keras` with [this beginner's tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rtatman/beginner-s-intro-to-rnn-s-in-r):

I'm going through the tutorial step by step, but I run into a weird error after adding the input layer. Here's the line causing the issue:

```
# our input layer
model %>%
    layer_dense(input_shape = dim(X_train)[2:3], units = max_len)
```

And this is the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: <Sequential name=sequential_6, built=False> (of type <class 'keras.src.models.sequential.Sequential'>)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
```

It must be related to my R installation, but I'm not sure where I went wrong. I installed the latest versions of R, RStudio, and Python from their official websites. I'm on Windows 10. Here's how I installed `keras`:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```